# Spaces down left and right side of iPad app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, autolayout

I have built an app that involves a UINavigationController with a UIViewController as root.

Then inside the UIViewController I have a UIView (top half) and a UITableView (bottom half).

I am using autolayout.

On the iPhone the UIView and UITableView go all the way to the left and right edges of the screen. On the iPad, however, there is about a 5 pixel space on the left and right side.

Has anyone seen this before and knows of a way of resolving it?

Comment: was your app developed in iOS 7 and now you are using latest SDK iOS8?

Comment: Nah. It was developed in iOS8 (just a week ago)

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out.  My autolayout values were wrong.

I had:

First Item = Superview.Trailing
Second Item = View.Trailing Margin

By adding removing 'Margin' on second item (so neither had margin) they then aligned correctly. (This is done by selecting dropdown next to first item and selecting 'Relative to Margin').  I also had to set the Constant = 0 (since no margins used now)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please Select deployment device Universal from Deployment info.

Comment: Yeah - already selected Universal when building the app .. but still not helping Im afraid. But thanks for suggestion.